# How to extract strings from a file

Tags: file, text

I have a web page source and I have to extrat all the strings containing a series of characters(for example:"http://www.stackoverflow.com") and put them in another file. the "http:// doesn't change but the text that follow untill the closing " change!

I don't know nothing about scripting(sigh) and I tried some script(even on stackoverflow) but they do different things

this does a different thing, I tried to play with it without success

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=: read -r c1 c2; do
    [[ $c1 == Node ]] && var=$c1
    [[ $c1 == INFO ]] && echo "$var$c2"
done < file.txt
end
```

I expect il scans a web page source and put all the selected strings in a selected file

Answer (score 1):

You can match text starting by `"http://` up to the next double-quote by using the following regex :

```
"http://[^"]*"
```

The `[^"]*` part matches any number of non-quote characters.

To extract such text from a file and write it to another, GNU `grep` will do the trick :

```
grep -o '"http://[^"]*"' sourceFile > targetFile
```

The `-o` option is used to make `grep` only output the matched string rather than the whole line that contains it.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/TeMa68).

Comment: thank you very much for the very fast answer!
it seems that it doesn't have the -o option but maybe it's my nas

[/share/Disk3/NathanNever/Script] # ./estrazione.sh
grep: invalid option -- o
BusyBox v1.01 (2019.07.29-21:32+0000) multi-call binary

Usage: grep [-ihHnqvs] PATTERN [FILEs...]

Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.

Comment: Ok, it worked really fine on another machine.
Thank you very much Aaron!

hugs from Italy :)

Comment: Looks like `-o` isn't defined by the POSIX standard bur rather is a GNU extension, I wasn't aware of that. I've edited my answer to reflect that, I'll add a POSIX alternative later if I find some time